# heroku support for Adobe experience management

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli, heroku-api

We are planning to use Heroku for one of our client who has mobile (Android and IOS) and desktop apps built on Adobe Experience Management. Can someone please let me know if it is possible? if yes, is there any documentation, solution approach available for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: include details what you have tried from you side

Comment: I tried asking Heroku support about if Heroku supports AEM and if there is any dcoumentation available on this. We are at very early stage of the project and still evaluating Heroku for AEM on Can it used and How it can be used.

Comment: Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note below points.

- Heroku will support deploying executable jars. [Click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files)
- Using AEM you can create executable jars. [Click here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/deploy.html)

Hence it is possible to host AEM apps in Heroku. Let me know in case of any queries.